# Time between request to database and response data on UI

Tags: performance-testing

I have to calculated the time between request sent ro database server and showing the data on UI. Is there any tool available which calculate the mentioned requirement?

Comment: Whats the UI written in? What kind of database? As is this question is unanswerable

Comment: database SQL server, and on UI it is table data. page is coded in ASP .Net. I want to calculate the exact time when data getting fetched from database and it shown on UI

Comment: Use F12 console for starters. It has browser side waits and timings. Then use SQL Profiler to measure execution times. From that you can derive all the timing segments

Answer (score 0):

There are many tools which can address this issue.  What you are looking at is a combination of a Graphical Virtual User and an API level virtual user with common timed events, such as a named timing record of GUI_Login and and API_Login.   The delta between the two times at a given load level represents the client overhead.   These capabilities have been available since the mid 1990's - Yes, over two decades!

What tools?  These tend to be the big classical tools that can work against any GUI: Segue/Borland/Microfocus SilkPerformer, Compuware/Microfocus QA Load, Mercury/HP/Microfocus LoadRunner, IBM/Rational Performance Tester.  There are likely a few others.   The webby tools generally only work against browsers as the full thick client - As you have mentioned DB this response assumes a traditional two-tier thick DB client is where you are seeking the delta measurement.